# d3: Why is enter selection not showing any transition for a donut chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3 library. I am trying to create a donut chart with transition on enter, update and exit selection. My code is inspired from this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hYuPb/1517/). But unlike this fiddle, no transition is happening in my code. Here is the code -

```
crm = [
    {name: 'SMR', value: 3097},
    {name: 'PSF', value: 3374},
    {name: 'Insurance', value: 1225}
]

 pieTween = function(d, i) {
      var s0;
      var e0;
      if(oldPieData[i]){
        s0 = oldPieData[i].startAngle;
        e0 = oldPieData[i].endAngle;
      } else if (!(oldPieData[i]) && oldPieData[i-1]) {
        s0 = oldPieData[i-1].endAngle;
        e0 = oldPieData[i-1].endAngle;
      } else if(!(oldPieData[i-1]) && oldPieData.length > 0){
        s0 = oldPieData[oldPieData.length-1].endAngle;
        e0 = oldPieData[oldPieData.length-1].endAngle;
      } else {
        s0 = 0;
        e0 = 0;
      }
      var i = d3.interpolate({startAngle: s0, endAngle: e0}, {startAngle: d.startAngle, endAngle: d.endAngle});
      return function(t) {
        var b = i(t);
        return arc(b);
      };
}

var pie = Math.PI * 2;
var w = 500,
    h = 500;
var ir = 45;
var duration = 250;
var chart = d3.select('.chart')
                .attr('width', w)
                .attr('height',h)

createPieChart = function(data){
    var radius = 200;
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach(data, function(item){
        total+=item.value;
    })

    color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .range(['#469AB2', '#F0AD4E', '#5CB85C', '#D9534F']);


    groups = chart.append('g')
                .attr('transform', 'translate('+w/2+','+ h/2 + ')');

    // group at the center of donut
    center_group = chart.append('g')
                        .attr("class", "center_group")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + (h/2) + ")");
    // displaying total calls at the center
    center_group.append('text')
                .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
                .text(total);

    arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(radius-60)
            .outerRadius(radius)

    pieChart = d3.layout.pie()
                .value(function(d){ return d.value; });

    oldPieData = pieChart(data);

    arcs = groups.selectAll('path')
            .data(pieChart(data))

    arcsEnter = arcs.enter().append('path')
                .each(function(d) { this._current = d; });

    arcsEnter.attr('class', 'arc')
            .attr('fill', function(d){ return color(d.data.value)})
            .transition().duration(duration).attrTween("d", pieTween)
}

createPieChart(crm);
```

Can someone please help me and tell me why is there no transition?

Here is my code [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayank_ninja/oaqu04jk/7/)

Comment: You need to have an initial value for the `d` attribute otherwise it will jump to the final value. So you need to figure out a zero state for `d`.

Comment: @CoolBlue How can I do that? Also in the given fiddle, I don't think d has been initialized

Comment: Yes, you're right actually, the tween manages the case when there is no previous data. OK, best thing is to convert the code in your question into a working snippet. Meanwhile, try this: `arcs.attr('class', 'arc')
            .attr('fill', function(d){ return color(d.data.value)})
            .transition().duration(duration).attrTween("d", pieTween)`.  The transition needs to be applied to the update+enter selection (which is the value returned by `selection.data()` after `selection.enter()` is called), not the enter selection.

Comment: @CoolBlue Thanks for the prompt reply. I replaced `arcsEnter` with `arcs` as you told to in the code snippet, but still no transition is happening. Waiting for your code snippet...

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstand me: I'm waiting for your code snippet. ;) If you convert the code in your question to a minimum, working example then we can find out the problem.

Comment: Where is your exit transition by the way?

Comment: @CoolBlue Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayank_ninja/oaqu04jk/2/). I have not written the exit transition yet

Comment: @CoolBlue I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayank_ninja/oaqu04jk/7/). Added an update button to update the donut and check for transitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the initial value of the oldPieData array, it already had the values for the new data when the transition started.

```js
crm = [
        {name: 'SMR', value: 3097},
        {name: 'PSF', value: 3374},
        {name: 'Insurance', value: 1225}
    ]


    pieTween = function(d, i) {
        var s0;
        var e0;
        if(oldPieData[i]){
            s0 = oldPieData[i].startAngle;
            e0 = oldPieData[i].endAngle;
        } else if (!(oldPieData[i]) && oldPieData[i-1]) {
            s0 = oldPieData[i-1].endAngle;
            e0 = oldPieData[i-1].endAngle;
        } else if(!(oldPieData[i-1]) && oldPieData.length > 0){
            s0 = oldPieData[oldPieData.length-1].endAngle;
            e0 = oldPieData[oldPieData.length-1].endAngle;
        } else {
            s0 = 0;
            e0 = 0;
        }
        var i = d3.interpolate({startAngle: s0, endAngle: e0}, {startAngle: d.startAngle, endAngle: d.endAngle});
        return function(t) {
            var b = i(t);
            return arc(b);
        };
    }

    var pie = Math.PI * 2;
    var w = 200,
        h = 180;
    var ir = 45;
    var duration = 250;
    var chart = d3.select('.chart')
        .attr('width', w)
        .attr('height',h);
    var pieChart = d3.layout.pie()
            .value(function(d){ return d.value; }),
        oldPieData = [];

    createPieChart = function(data){
        var radius = h/2;
        var total = 0;
        data.forEach(function(item){
            total+=item.value;
        }),

        color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .range(['#469AB2', '#F0AD4E', '#5CB85C', '#D9534F']);


        groups = chart.append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate('+w/2+','+ h/2 + ')');

        // group at the center of donut
        var center_group = chart.append('g')
            .attr("class", "center_group")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + (h/2) + ")");
        // displaying total calls at the center
        center_group.append('text')
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .text(total);

        arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(radius-h/4)
            .outerRadius(radius)

        var arcs = groups.selectAll('path')
            .data((pieChart(data))),
            arcsEnter = arcs.enter().append('path');

        arcs.attr('class', 'arc')
            .attr('fill', function(d){ return color(d.data.value)})
            .transition().duration(duration).attrTween("d", pieTween);
        return data;
    };

    createPieChart(crm);
```

```css
.shady-background {
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
        }

        div.shady-background{
            padding: 0.5%;
        }

        div.shady-background>span{
            margin-left: 30px;
        }
        #main-container {
            top:6.8em;
            position: relative;
        }

        .chart rect {
            fill: steelblue;
        }

        .chart text {
            /*  fill: white;*/
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        #pie-chart-div {
            position: relative;
            top: 6em;
        }

        .chart {
            position: relative;
            /* top: 2em;*/
            left: 5em;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg class="chart"></svg>
```

---

### Here is a clean version...

```js
var crm = (function() {
        var prevData = [];
        return function crm(f) {
            var max = 10000;

            oldPieData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prevData));
            prevData = f([
                {name: 'SMR', value: Math.random() * max},
                {name: 'PSF', value: Math.random() * max},
                {name: 'Insurance', value: Math.random() * max},
                {name: 'Other', value: Math.random() * max}
            ])
        }
    })();

    pieTween = function(d, i) {
        var s0;
        var e0;
        if(oldPieData[i]){
            s0 = oldPieData[i].startAngle;
            e0 = oldPieData[i].endAngle;
        } else if (!(oldPieData[i]) && oldPieData[i-1]) {
            s0 = oldPieData[i-1].endAngle;
            e0 = oldPieData[i-1].endAngle;
        } else if(!(oldPieData[i-1]) && oldPieData.length > 0){
            s0 = oldPieData[oldPieData.length-1].endAngle;
            e0 = oldPieData[oldPieData.length-1].endAngle;
        } else {
            s0 = 0;
            e0 = 0;
        }
        var i = d3.interpolate({startAngle: s0, endAngle: e0}, {startAngle: d.startAngle, endAngle: d.endAngle});
        return function(t) {
            var b = i(t);
            return arc(b);
        };
    };

    var pie = Math.PI * 2;
    var w = 200,
        h = 190;
    var ir = 45;
    var duration = 500;
    var chart = d3.select('.chart')
            .attr('width', w)
            .attr('height',h)
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate('+w/2+','+ h/2 + ')'),
        pieChart = d3.layout.pie()
            .value(function(d){ return d.value; })
            .sort(null),
        oldPieData = [],

        groups = chart.append ("g")
            .attr("class", "groups"),
    // group at the center of donut
        center_group = chart.append('g')
            .attr("class", "center_group")
            .append('text')
            .attr({'text-anchor': 'middle', dy: "0.35em"});

    createPieChart = function(data){
        var radius = 92;
        var pieData,
            color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .range(['#469AB2', '#F0AD4E', '#5CB85C', '#D9534F'])
                .domain(data.map(function(d){return d.name}));

        // displaying total calls at the center
        center_group.text(d3.format(",.1f")(d3.sum(data, function(d){return d.value})));

        arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(radius-50)
            .outerRadius(radius);

        var arcs = groups.selectAll('path')
            .data((pieData = pieChart(data)), function(d){return d.data.name});
        arcs.enter().append('path')
            .attr('class', 'arc');

        arcs.attr('fill', function(d){ return color(d.data.name)})
            .transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attrTween("d", pieTween)
            .ease("bounce");
        return pieData;
    };

    crm(createPieChart);
    window.setInterval(function(){crm(createPieChart)}, 3000)
```

```css
.shady-background {
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
        }

        div.shady-background{
            padding: 0.5%;
        }

        div.shady-background>span{
            margin-left: 30px;
        }
        #main-container {
            top:6.8em;
            position: relative;
        }

        .chart rect {
            fill: steelblue;
        }

        .chart text {
            /*  fill: white;*/
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        #pie-chart-div {
            position: relative;
            top: 6em;
        }

        .chart {
            position: relative;
            /* top: 2em;*/
            left: 5em;
        }
```

```html
<svg class="chart"></svg>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
```

---

Comment: OK, no problem.  By the way, it's much better if you use the snippet tool to post working code here instead of a link to jsFiddle.

Comment: One more thing, now where should i initialize `oldPieData`. If I place it at the end of the function, still the transition doesn't happen

Comment: Yes, it has to be done after the transition has _completed_. If you put it at the end of the function that's after the transition is _scheduled_ but _before_ it begins...

Comment: So where should I do it? Does d3 fire any event when transitions are completed?

Comment: Do it just before you generate the new data.